# Expendable listView ui design?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am facing a problem .

I need to design a UI basically i have done it but some one suggest me to design with `ExpandableListView`.

I am not getting any idea to design with `ExpandableListView`.

1-is it possible make this design with `ExpandableListView`.

if it is please guide me to design it with my desire view.

[image]

**Problem:**- In my list items two contains button and others are text only.
          That's why i want to know the possibility of this design ,it can be done or not.

Comment: Is it like some views will be hidden in the beginning and on click of that button you are expanding ?

Comment: yes..onclick of item ..child view will be visible

Comment: The above layout which you want to design is also possible with `ListView`. In which you have to manage the show and hide of the button for each items based on its positions.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Documents and these tutorials

[ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

[Expandable ListView in ANDROID](http://www.coderzheaven.com/expandable-listview-android-simpleexpandablelistadapter-simple-example/)

[Android Expandable ListView simple Example in android](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html.)

you can expand list item by using this

```
ExpandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() 
{               
   public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) 
   { 
       // your code...
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans..but i want to know above design is possible or not in expandable list view.

Comment: You want to add one textview and one button in every list item, am i right?. if yes it's possible by customising your list view as like as you want . look at customise expandable listview..

Comment: no i want to add button only in two list item ...see my design image above

Comment: that is also possible, make it like this in getView() method of CustomAdapter depending on positions just hide the button when you don't want. just customise the ListView with Custom adapter..